# can we create apk file from expo code or can we deploy our apk which is build in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Can we create APK file from expo code or can we deploy our APK which is build in expo. means can we create and deploy our APK file to Play Store and App Store without ejecting expo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can upload expo apps to the app store or play store.

Check out the official docs to upload the expo app:

https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/